# d3 nested variable data binding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a newbie to D3 and trying to solve a not so easy problem (at least to me!) Here's my sample dataset.

```js
var data = [
    {"x":1000, "y": {"10":100, "10.2":200, "10.3":300, "10.4":600}},
    {"x":1001, "y": {"9.2":60, "9.6":400, "10.1":20, "10.8":320, "11":20, "8.8":722}},
    {"x":1002, "y": {"9.8":80, "9.9":600, "9.2":40}},
    {"x":1003, "y": {"10.1":60, "10.3":400, "10.8":360, "9.6":88}},
    {"x":1004, "y": {"9.8":20, "10.4":450}}
];
```

How can I bind this using d3 to create rectangles with the attributes `x=` value of x, `y=` keys of the y object, `width=` values of the y object and `height=` any given constant?

Essentially, this will have a variable number of rectangles for each x based on the number of elements in the `y` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, indeed, a little bit complicated, mainly because your `y` property contains just one object, instead of an array of objects.

My solution here uses `d3.entries`, which, according to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#entries):

> Returns an **array** containing the property keys and values of the specified object (an associative array). Each entry is an object with a key and value attribute, such as {key: "foo", value: 42}. The order of the returned array is undefined. (emphasis mine)

It's important having an array, so we can bind the data (since the `data()` method accepts only three things: an array, a function or nothing).

So, in this solution, I'm using the outer objects to append groups...

```
var groups = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g");
```

... and the `y` object of each outer object to append the rectangles...

```
var rects = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.entries(d.y)
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect");
```

... and using `d3.entries()` to convert the object into an array of objects, which can be used with `data()`.

Here is a demo (I changed your actual values, so we can better see the rectangles):

```js
var data = [{
  "x": 100,
  "y": {
    "10": 100,
    "20": 200,
    "26": 300,
    "35": 400
  }
}, {
  "x": 20,
  "y": {
    "50": 60,
    "59.6": 400,
    "70.1": 20,
    "80.8": 320,
    "88": 20,
    "98.8": 722
  }
}, {
  "x": 30,
  "y": {
    "109.8": 80,
    "119.9": 600,
    "139.2": 40
  }
}, {
  "x": 10,
  "y": {
    "150.1": 60,
    "170.3": 400,
    "190.8": 360,
    "209.6": 88
  }
}, {
  "x": 50,
  "y": {
    "259.8": 20,
    "280.4": 450
  }
}];

var colours = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var constant = 5;

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var groups = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colours(i)
  })

var rects = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.entries(d.y)
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

rects.attr("y", function(d) {
    return +d.key
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.value
  })
  .attr("height", constant)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().x;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="300"></svg>
```

Pay attention to how I get the `y` and `width` values and, specially, the `x` value (accessing the parent's datum).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply! While I try to understand the solution, I just want to mention that the values of `y` are an ideal solution from a data pull perspective, not a required one. If there can be a cleaner solution with some re-arranging of y values like to return an array of keys and values, I'd be okay to change the data pull to return such a result or change it in the JS layer itself. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not following your comment... My answer **is** returning an array of keys and values.

Comment: What I meant is, I'd be OK to change the `y` object to an array, if it would make it any easier/clean in d3. E.g for the last record it would look like this: `[{"k":9.8,"v":20}, {"k":10.4, "v":450}]`. But I guess it is really not needed, as your solution works great! Thank you

Comment: That is **precisely** what my code is doing. It is changing the object into an array.